# Magento 2: Custom module admin configuration access errror

Tags: admin, magento2-enterprise, object, magento242

I have used a custom module and when click on the admin configuration module menu throws the error.

This error is facing only in `production` mode. And faced issue when run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` command

if we can run command `rm -rf generated/*` and run only `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` then it is working fine.

I have checked this issue is a compilation issue.

**Admin custom module menu access error:**

**Error:**

```
Type Error occurred when creating object: Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\ProductFilterGroup\Grid\Collection\Interceptor, Argument 1 passed to Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\ProductFilterGroup\Grid\Collection\Interceptor::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface, instance of Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory given, called in /magento242/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
Exception in /magento242/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:131
```

**File path:** `Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/ProductFilterGroup/Grid/Collection.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\ProductFilterGroup\Grid;

use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\ProductFilterGroup\Collection as GroupAttributeCollection;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document as GroupAttributeModel;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Collection extends GroupAttributeCollection implements SearchResultInterface
{
    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $aggregations;

    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @var Json
     */
    protected $serializer;

    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request,
        Json $serializer,
        EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = GroupAttributeModel::class,
        $connection = null,
        AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }

    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute')],
            'main_table.attribute_id = secondTable.attribute_id',
            ['frontend_label as attribute']
        );
    }

    protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {
        $filters = $this->request->getParam('filters');
        $storeId = $this->request->getParam('store', 1);
        if (isset($filters['group_title'])) {
            $match = sprintf(
                '%%%s%%',
                substr(
                    $this->serializer->serialize([$storeId => $filters['group_title']]),
                    1,
                    -1
                )
            );
            $this->addFieldToFilter('group_title', ['like' => $match]);
        }

        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }

    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }

    
    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }

   
    public function getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($this->_getAllIdsSelect($limit, $offset), $this->_bindParams);
    }

    
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    
    public function setSearchCriteria(SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**File path:** `Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\ProductFilterGroup\Collection.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\ProductFilterGroup;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    const MODEL = 'Vendor\Module\Model\ProductFilterGroup';
    const RESOURCE_MODEL = 'Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\ProductFilterGroup';

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(self::MODEL, self::RESOURCE_MODEL);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what is the permanent solution for this issue?

Comment: Can you post your module code, so that we can get some more details and help ?

Comment: @NarendraVyas I have post module code. please check.

Comment: Can you post "Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\ProductFilterGroup\Collection"  as well.
I think there is something wrong in the first parameter that you are passing in parent class constructor.
So need to see what is the parent class.

Comment: @NarendraVyas posted. check now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check class from which you extends this Collection class

According to me Grid/Collection.php class should be extends from "**Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult**"

Comment: I have checked but not working.